# Crash when using a global object, but not when using a local object

Tags: c++, class, constructor, segmentation-fault

I am trying to use [libconfig](https://github.com/hyperrealm/libconfig) to create a configuration file for my program. There are two scenarios, one which works perfectly (local scope object) and the other which fails (global scope object). I am trying to understand why one fails while the other succeeds, as it is my understanding that both are definitions which create the same object (just in different scope).

1st (does not work): I define a Config object in the global scope. Then I call readFile on the Config object. The program crashes here.

```
#include <libconfig.h++>

libconfig::Config cfg;

int __attribute__((constructor)) Init()
{
  cfg.readFile("/home/jalius/csgo-internal/hack.cfg");
}
```

2nd (works): I define a local Config object and call readFile on it.

```
#include <libconfig.h++>

int __attribute__((constructor)) Init()
{
  libconfig::Config cfg;
  cfg.readFile("/home/jalius/csgo-internal/hack.cfg");
}
```

Comment: What's the run-time error?

Comment: How would I go about extracting that information? This shared library in injected to another process with dlopen. I have gdb open on the process, and see that the main thread received SIGSEGV while inside libconfig.c somewhere (I don't have debug symbols).

Comment: `SIGSEGV` signal represents segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are calling `int __attribute__((constructor)) Init()` function at that time the `cfg` object is not created *in your case*. Because the order of calling functions decorated with attribute `constructor` and C++ objects with static storage duration is unspecified. Since object doesn't exists so you are getting segmentation fault error i.e. `SIGSEGV` signal.

Following is an extract from [GCC website](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes):

> at present, the order in which constructors for C++ objects with static storage duration and functions decorated with attribute `constructor` are invoked is unspecified. In mixed declarations, attribute `init_priority` can be used to impose a specific ordering.

See `constructor` section on [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that your function `int __attribute__((constructor)) Init()` will be called **before** the `Config` object is constructed.

When you try to read from it, you might actually try to access an unconstructed object. This will cause undefined behavior.

When you create it locally, there is a guarantee that your object will be initialized fully before you use it.

---

### Experiment:

```
#include <iostream>

enum {
    OBJECT_CONSTRUCTOR,
    FUNCTION_CONSTRUCTOR,
};

int order[10], cur = 0;

class TestClass {
  public:
   TestClass() { order[cur++] = OBJECT_CONSTRUCTOR; }
   ~TestClass() { }
};

TestClass abc;
int __attribute__((constructor)) Init() {
   order[cur++] = FUNCTION_CONSTRUCTOR;
}

int main ()
{
    std::cout << "Order of execution:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < cur; i++)
    {
        switch(order[i])
        {
            case OBJECT_CONSTRUCTOR:
                std::cout<<"Object Constructor\n";
                break;
            case FUNCTION_CONSTRUCTOR:
                std::cout<<"Function Constructor\n";
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Results:

```
Order of execution:
Function Constructor
Object Constructor
```

Comment: Interesting. I assumed that it would be guaranteed that all global variables would be constructed just as in main.